# Adding a last login row to a query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add a last login field to a current mysql query.
The table containing the login details is tbluserlogins, and the timestamp I need is nTimestamp.

I have tried several joins, using max but having a hard time getting the needed results.

```
$sql = "SELECT tblusers.*, tblaffiliates.sForename AS sAffForename, tblaffiliates.sSurname AS sAffSurname 
                FROM tblusers LEFT JOIN tblusers AS tblaffiliates ON tblusers.nAffiliate_ID = tblaffiliates.nUser_ID ";
```

To clarify, I need to add some additional code into the above query, to obtain the last login, from the tbluserlogins table.

tbluserlogins stores each login storing a unix timestamp.
I need to retrieve the timestamp from the last login.
I need to do this, using a join with the above mysql code, so I can make the result sortable using this value.

the tbluserlogins uses a shared nUser_ID column.

Comment: please clearify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a sub-query which returns the last login and left join with your original query. For example:

```
SELECT tblusers.*, 
tblaffiliates.sForename AS sAffForename, 
tblaffiliates.sSurname AS sAffSurname, 
L.LastLogin
FROM tblusers 
LEFT JOIN tblusers AS tblaffiliates 
ON tblusers.nAffiliate_ID = tblaffiliates.nUser_ID 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ID, MAX(logindate) AS 'LastLogin' FROM tbluserlogins GROUP BY ID) L
ON tblusers.nAffiliate_ID = L.ID;
```